# When implementing the Iterable interface, shouldn't the iterator() method return a clone of the collection?

Tags: java, iterator

I have seen many examples of how to implement the Iterable interface where the iterator() method merely returns the original collection to be iterated. But this seems to defy part of the purpose of an iterator, in that one should be able to iterate over said collection without worrying about the collection changing underneath you. Shouldn't the iterator() method of an Iterable always return a clone of the collection? And, preferably, a deep clone?

I know, answers to this question may be partially based on opinion, which is verboten. However, what I am trying to get at is the original intent of the Iterable interface, NOT what people may or may not have decided to do with it.

Comment: I think it's up to the collection's implementation to decide this.

Comment: It depends, in general, most `Collection`(s) AFAIK use a fail fast `Iterator` for that reason.

Comment: This is absolutely not the original implementation of the `Iterable` interface.  That would make it absolutely impossible to change the collection elements as you iterate over it, which is totally a useful thing.

Comment: There are collections that do (sort of) what you suggest. An `Iterator` for a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` holds a reference to the backing `Object[]` at the point the `Iterator` is constructed. Any writes to the `List` while iteration is in progress create a completely fresh array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But this seems to defy part of the purpose of an iterator, in that one should be able to iterate over said collection without worrying about the collection changing underneath you.

This is not one of the guarantees an iterator gives you. In fact, there is a special exception [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) created for the purposes of alerting the programmer to the situation when the collection he is iterating has been modified underneath him.

> Shouldn't the iterator() method of an Iterable always return a clone of the collection? And, preferably, a deep clone?

It definitely could. However, this would be massively expensive, especially for an operation so fundamental. Think about it: every time you wish to run a for-each loop on a collection, the library goes "oh, wait a minute, I have to clone this entire 1000-element thing before letting you iterate". This would be very slow, and prompt programmers to stop using iterators in situations when they think the performance is critical (this includes a lot of situations when performance is not actually critical, too).

On top of that, Java has no idea how to clone your elements, even if you implement `Cloneable` (because [`Cloneable` is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)).

Of course you always have a choice of cloning a collection yourself, and iterating over it for better isolation of concurrently running processes. However, in this situation the programmer needs to make the decision to pay for such isolation, which is different from the library making this decision for him.

Comment: Thank you. Three hours of digging around got me nothing. You answered my question in under 2 minutes.